# Spring-security custom form not loading(throuwing page not found)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, velocity

I have been working on Spring-mvc with apache velocity and now stuck with Spring-security integration.
I went through the documentation and examples provided by mkyong: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/

**Problem:** Every other request is going to controller but "/login" is not reaching controller as console doesnot show sysout value of model object.

Here is my spring-security.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/sample.html" authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="userName" password-parameter="password" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login?success" />
    <csrf />
</http>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
    @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
    logger.info("Login Page Redirect..");
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
  if (error != null) {
    model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
  }

  if (logout != null) {
    model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
  }
  model.setViewName("loginPage");
  System.out.println("Print Model:"+model);
  return model;

}
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www......>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.anksys.bgms"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<!-- This bean sets up the Velocity environment for us based on a root path 
    for templates. Optionally, a properties file can be specified for more control 
    over the Velocity environment, but the defaults are pretty same for file 
    based template loading. -->
<bean id="velocityConfig"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/velocity/" />
</bean>

<!-- Velocity template resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutView" />
    <property name="layoutUrl" value="base_template.vm"></property>
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="attributesMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="authz"><bean class="com.anksys.bgms.security.VelocityUserDetails"></bean></entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- JSP resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="2" />
</bean>
```

loginPage.jsp Path:

webapp/WEB-INF/views/loginPage.jsp

Please suggest any work around..

Thanks in advance..

Following are the lines from logs.

```
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG DefaultRedirectStrategy:36 - Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8081/BGMS/login'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:300 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:148 - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:90 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@243b81d0. A new one will be created.
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:127 - Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /j_spring_security_logout
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG DefaultSavedRequest:309 - pathInfo: both null (property equals)
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG DefaultSavedRequest:309 - queryString: both null (property equals)
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG DefaultSavedRequest:331 - requestURI: arg1=/BGMS/user/sample.html; arg2=/BGMS/login (property not equals)
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG HttpSessionRequestCache:75 - saved request doesn't match
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:102 - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faa1b5a: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff6a82: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 8373E425131980C1C5DF87CB932C8AB0; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/user/**'
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:185 - Public object - authentication not attempted
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:323 - /login reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:300 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:115 - Chain processed normally
2015-01-28 10:02:25 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Can you please change the access control expression from isAnonymouse() to permitAll. If you still can't access the login form please share more info. Like spring-security logs (debug level) or better a simple app with the same problem.

Comment: Even logs are empty......no error except access denied for user/**

Comment: Following are the last lines from logs, as per my understanding...i found that request is not dispatched properly to controller with mapping "/login"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry!!

did a mistake in web.xml url mapping tags.